# new BufferedReader in class Files cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, json, path

[image]

```
List< String> list = new ArrayList<>();

try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(path))) {

    //br returns as stream and convert it into a List
    list = br.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());

} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String s : list) {
    sb.append(s);
}

String json = sb.toString();
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
obj = parser.parse(json);
```

I am getting this error please help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you are using java 7 which has only one version of 
Files.newBufferedReader method which takes Charset as a second argument
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedReader(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)
In Java 8 you will find the method you need
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedReader-java.nio.file.Path-

Comment: But possible warning: The one argument `Files#newBufferedReader` method uses `UTF-8` by default, which may not be what the OP wants to use.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Files#newBufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedReader(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)) method takes a mandatory second parameter which is a character set.  If you try the following code, the error should go away:

```
List< String> list = new ArrayList<>();

Charset charset = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");

try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(path), charset)) {
    list = br.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This assumes that your file is encoded in `US-ASCII`, though if you had another encoding, you could specify that as well.  For example, if your file were `UTF-8` encoded, you could use:

```
Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
```

**Edit:**

After the seeing the accepted answer, I noticed that Java 8 introduced a one argument version of `Files#newBufferedReader` which just takes a single path as input.  However, this is really a helper method which just calls the following:

```
return newBufferedReader(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

In other words, it defaults to using `UTF-8` encoding.  If you want to use some other encoding, then my answer is probably the best approach for you.

Comment: errors reduced..but its showing  connot find symbol on lines

Comment: @VaisakhMA We are not here to debug your code, line-by-line.  I have addressed your direct question.  If your code has other problem, then you should have highlighted that as well.

Comment: When i am using your code its showing thats y i asked :)

Comment: @VaisakhMA Try adding `import java.nio.charset.Charset;` to the list of imports at the top of your file.  This is the only change coming from me which I think would be causing this.